# pg_dump on docker-compose down

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

How can I run my custom down function in `docker compose down`?

Basically what I want is to run the `pg_dump` (e.g. `docker exec -t blog-database-dev pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > data/blog_dev.sql`) after shutting down my containers, so that I can push my SQL file to my git repository and have the same dev database for all hosts.

Additionally I want to copy that dumped SQL-file back to my postgres container whenever I start the container using `docker compose up`.

So far I have this docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  blog-database:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.database
    image: blog-database
    container_name: blog-database-dev
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: blog
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
ADD ./data/blog_dev.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I would also welcome if you have an alternative/better solution for the problem I have. I just want to share my local database with other developers.